# AssertionError: Failed to generate surface file using command

Tags: python, biopython

I get msms.exe has stopped working with this simple script, please help me debug it. I tried it with a different pdb, same result. You might want to take a look at [ResidueDepth.py](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/biopython/biopython/master/Bio/PDB/ResidueDepth.py).

AssertionError: Failed to generate surface file using command:
msms -probe_radius 1.5 -if C:\Users\Ahmad\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp2pa74le2 -of C:\Users\Ahmad\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpf7zqwkg6 > C:\Users\Ahmad\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpncvn65g4

```
from Bio.PDB import PDBParser, ResidueDepth

p = PDBParser()
s = p.get_structure("X", '1crn.pdb')
model = s[0]

rd = ResidueDepth(model, '1crn.pdb')
print(rd[(chain_id, res_id)])
```

Answer (score 0):

The ResidueDepth code depends on pdb_to_xyzr, which is a BASH script that cannot run on windows. An issue was created regarding this problem [here](https://github.com/biopython/biopython/issues/1140%E2%80%8B).